# java - check all of array values then check the else if

Tags: java, arrays, for-loop

i have a for loop that i want to check some values in my array

```
for (Hero myHeroes : heroes) {
                if (myHeroes.getCurrentHP() <= 60) {
                    world.castAbility(hero, healerHeal, myHeroes.getCurrentCell());
                } else if() {


                }
            }
```

what should i do if i want to check all of `myHeroes` `HPs` and after that if they weren't below 60 check the else-if part

( sorry if my english is bad )

Comment: add a second loop

Comment: You should probably try streams and allMatch

Comment: So you want to check all Hero objects and if one of them is below 60, you want to do something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this is what you mean.

```
boolean wasAHeroBelowSixtyHp = false;
for (Hero myHeroes : heroes) {
    if (myHeroes.getCurrentHP() <= 60) {
        world.castAbility(hero, healerHeal, myHeroes.getCurrentCell());
        wasAHeroBelowSixtyHp = true;
    }
}
if (wasAHeroBelowSixtyHp) {
    // do something
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
   boolean allOver60 = true;
   for(Hero myHeroes : heroes)
   {
      if ( myHeroes.getCurrentHP() <= 60 )
      {
         world.castAbility( hero, healerHeal, myHeroes.getCurrentCell() );
         allOver60 = false;
      }
   }
   if( allOver60 )
   {
      doSth();
   }
```